# How to run jsf mojarra 2.3 in wildfly 13 with netbeans 8.2?

Tags: jsf, jboss, wildfly

I created a project in netbeans and I add jboss_jsf-api_2.3 and after I created my faces_config.xml. But I have a error:

One or more services were unable to start due to one or more indirect dependencies not being available

faces config is:

```html
<faces-config
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_3.xsd"
    version="2.3">
</faces-config>
```

and my pom is:

```html
<dependencies>
   
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-jsf-api_2.3_spec</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.5.SP1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: Why did you not set the jsf api to provided?

Comment: Yes I put <scope>provided</scope> now, but now I write "FacesContext.class.getPackage().getImplementationVersion()" and the result is " 2.2.13.SP2"  I don't now how I can change to jsf 2.3

Comment: So you read all in http://wildfly.org/news/2018/05/30/WildFly13-Final-Released/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although Wildfly 13 contains **most** JavaEE 8 features, it by default starts in JavaEE 7 mode which is 'just' JSF 2.2.

From the very recent [WildFly 13 release documentation](http://wildfly.org/news/2018/05/30/WildFly13-Final-Released/)

> By default WildFly 13 launches in EE7 mode. In order to use these new capabilities you have to enable EE8 preview mode. This can be accomplished by passing the ee8.preview.mode property during startup:
>
> `./standalone.sh -Dee8.preview.mode=true`

There are other options too to enable this. From the same docs:

> Alternatively, this can be achieved by launching the server using the new standalone-ee8.xml configuration, which simply includes the property in the config.
>
> `./standalone.sh -c standalone-ee8.xml`
>
> The CLI can also be used to modify the existing configuration to add this property. For example:
>
> `embed-server --admin-only=true
>   /system-property=ee8.preview.mode:add(value=true)
>   stop-embedded-server`

You should then have JSF 2.3

Comment: Yes it was the solution. Thanks

Comment: You are allowed (advised even) to accept an answer and upvote it if it was really helpful https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers